# Some bug with UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have problem with  UILocalNotification. It fires twice. Why??
Here's my part of code where notofication [is created (+ debug info + result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29AOF.png).

I have spent 3 hour in searching. But didnt find nothing.

Comment: Please provide code as a text, not as an image.

Comment: do you schedule it twice maybe? schedules are persisted across applicationn launches

Comment: these are probably just stray notifications that you had set earlier. You can cancel all notifications and then set them again and try again.

Comment: Daij-Djan, yes. I found bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try cancelling all previous local notifications from AppDelegate inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications();`